# mysql query of coverage

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table of entries with a startdatetime and enddatetime, I want to be able to see overlap like employee coverage.  For instance I have 10 employees on shift with different start times and end times and I want to be able to query by hour and see how many employees are available per hour.

I had not tried because I did not find a place to start, I do something similar when they is incoming tasks at a specific time to see how many in each hour, but I am trying to see coverage in each hour of the day based on when an employee starts and ends, like 8 hour shift, 12 hours shift, etc..  So That I can see that I have 2, 3, 4, etc... coverage and map to number of tasks that come in and are planned.  Something below looks promising but its only for 1 time for each query, would like a query that can bring back each hour and how many cover in each hour.

Any help would be great.

Comment: "For example " . . . Please edit your question with sample data and desired results so we can all visualize the example.

Comment: Post the things which you already tried

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as TOTAL 
FROM table
WHERE '2015-05-28 12:00:00' 
BETWEEN startTime and endTime
```

Obviously you need to change this `'2015-05-28 12:00:00'` with the desidered date/time you're looking for.

Add others condition if needed...

**EDIT**

Adding the extra request:

Grouping by date and hour gives you the total count of coverage in a single hour per day.

```
SELECT date(date_start) as DAY, hour(date_start) as HOUR, count(*) as TOTAL 
FROM table
group by date(date_start), hour(date_start)
```

You can abviously add one or more condition.
ie. in this example below you'll get the total rows per hour in a single day (specified)

```
SELECT date(date_start) as DAY, hour(date_start) as HOUR, count(*) as TOTAL 
FROM table
WHERE date('2015-05-28') = date(startTime)
group by date(date_start), hour(date_start)
```

Comment: I edited above to give more info.  This looks promising if I can do it for each hour in the day in one query.

Comment: This seems close, but the data I have is in time and out time, but the are there for several hours.  This answer does not calculation but with the data I have to key off of, I have to figure out how to span each hour they are there and who else is in during those hours and count them.  Thats where I am stuck how to take the times they are in and then out and have each hour time period they are there and who else is. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try adding the `date(date_end)` in both the `group by` and `select`

Comment: Nothing yet, some getting close but nothing giving me coverage for each hour they are in.  I only get coverage based on who comes in on that hour, not who is already in.